# Bootstrap Navigation Bar Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

This is only my second question here on Stack overflow so if there is any additional information you need or clarification needed on anything I say, please don't hesitate to ask.
I tried looking into this question and did find some people here with a similar issue, but none of the fixes that helped with them worked for me.

I am looking to have my navigation bar hidden when the `max width` doesn't exceed more than `767px.` When it goes below that pixel amount, it should become a drop down menu that should collapse and expand when clicked by the button. This does not seem to be working for me.

My code is as follows

**HTML**

```
<header class="pull-center" id="masthead">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="img1"></div>
        <div id="img2"></div>
        <div id="img3"></div>
        <div id="img4"></div>
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <a class="brand brand-ctg" href="#section-1"><span></span></a>
            CTG
            <span></span>
        </a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#section-2">Demo Reel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-3">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a class="brand brand-ctg" href="#section-1"> <span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-4">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.colortheblog.com" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav-collapse .nav > li {
        float: left !important;
    }
    .navbar .in .nav li {
       display: block;
       float: none;
       width:100%;
    }
    .navbar .nav > li > a {
        color: #fff !important;
        float: none;
        margin-right: -3px !important;
        padding: 0 40px 10px !important;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .navbar .nav {
        margin-top: 0 !important;
        position: fixed!important;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .nav-collapse .brand {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .navbar .nav .active a,
    .navbar .nav > li > a:hover,
    .navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
        background-color: transparent;
        box-shadow: none;
        color: #2d2e2d !important;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom,
    .navbar-static-top {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom {
        position: static;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-bottom {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-inner,
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-inner {
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .navbar .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar .brand {
        margin: -10px 40px 0 0;
    }
    .nav-collapse {
        clear: both;
    }
    .nav-collapse .nav {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0 15px;
    }
    .nav-collapse .nav > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .nav-collapse .nav > li > a {
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    .nav-collapse .nav > .divider-vertical {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-collapse .nav .nav-header {
        color: #555555;
        text-shadow: none;
    }
    .nav-collapse .nav > li > a,
    .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
        padding: 9px 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #555555;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .nav-collapse .btn {
        padding: 4px 10px 4px;
        font-weight: normal;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
    .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu li + li a {
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
    .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:hover,
    .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .nav > li > a,
    .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
        color: #999999;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover {
        background-color: #111111;
    }
    .nav-collapse.in .btn-group {
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
        float: none;
        display: none;
        max-width: none;
        margin: 0 15px;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .nav-collapse .open > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:before,
    .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu:after {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu .divider {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-collapse .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before, .nav-collapse .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-collapse .navbar-form,
    .nav-collapse .navbar-search {
        float: none;
        padding: 15px 15px;
        margin: 15px 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }
    .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .navbar-form,
    .navbar-inverse .nav-collapse .navbar-search {
        border-top-color: #111111;  
        border-bottom-color: #111111;
    }
    .navbar .nav-collapse .nav.pull-right {
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .nav-collapse,
    .nav-collapse.collapse {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 0;
        background: #3b3b3b;
    }
    .navbar .btn-navbar {
        background:url(http://www.colorthegrayscale.com/images/icons/hover-teal.png);
        display: block;
        width: 25px;
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
    }
    .navbar-static .navbar-inner {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    .navbar .brand.brand-ctg span {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

**EDIT 1**
Tried to fix it, but still having my issue. I know some CSS is making the toggle button not work, I just can't seem to figure out what. For the sake of simply showing all my work in one place, you can find the test site **[here](http://www.colorthegrayscale.com/CTG%20Developer/)**

Comment: This is basic functionality for twitter bootstrap, there should be no extra CSS necessary.  So two questions: are you including twitters Javascript and do you have the viewport metatag set in the <head> tag?

Comment: This is the metatag I was referring to:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: @DanOrlovsky For the purposes of simply not knowing how to convey what I need, I'm going to provide a link to what I currently am working on. I feel like there is something conflicting with the button, making it not work, but I'm going a bit crazy trying to figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the bootstrap CSS styles when it is not need, so here is an example of a simple `navbar` based on twitter bootstrap:

**[Bootply DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/sf8qxz47tc)**

#### Snippet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

See Twitter Bootstrap **[Navbar Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)**

### EDIT: Based on your comment/updated question

here is your issue:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                <!-- <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> -->
                <a class="brand brand-ctg" href="#section-1"><span>CTG</span></a>
</a>
```

you  are opening an `a` inside another `a` and that's invalid HTML. Here's how to fix it (according to Docs):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="brand brand-ctg" href="#section-1"><span>CTG</span></a>
```

### EDIT2:

I was looking and you are using an old version of `bootstrap.css`  (v.2.2.1), the latest stable is 3.3.6, and you are missing the `bootstrap.js` (which make the menu to trigger when it is collapsed)

Comment: I tried what you said and am not seeming to get it. I've been fiddling with it and I know there's some CSS overriding the button, but I can't seem to find what. I've added a link to my prototype site so you can see what's going on in the original post. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Added in the code (I think the first option is the one I'll need), but it's still not working properly (though it is recognized as a button now. That's a start!).
When clicked, it should trigger the div "nav-collapse" to go from hidden to dropping down and showing the nav bar selections ("Demo", "Portfolio", ext.)
Any ideas?
Thanks again for your continued help :)

Comment: Wow, I feel like such a heel. Thanks, adding back in the bootstrap.js did the trick! Making stupid mistakes like this sucks, but I'm really grateful you saw what was going on!